# Jenkins job continue on last failed step in previous build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

Is it possible to configure Jenkins to start from the failed step in the previous build?

Here is an example:

If build #9 fails on step 23 build #10 should start from step 23, not from first step as it is by default?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Naginator plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) dependent on how your build steps are set up

Comment: How would that work? AFAICT it only supports rerunning matrix axes, not linear build steps.

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise [checkpoints](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/workflow-sect-checkpoint.html) allow something like this for Workflow jobs, subject to certain restrictions. I do not know of any analogous feature for freestyle projects.